# NPM dependencies installed with `yarn add` have a `+deprecated` suffix in the `package.json`

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json, yarnpkg

I'm considering migrating fully to yarn but I think I don't fully understand how it works. Any specific reason to why this is happening? I tried with `yarn add phantomjs --dev --exact` but the listing on my package.json says:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "phantomjs": "2.1.7+deprecated"
  }
```

What does this `+deprecated` suffix mean? and will this keep work with `npm install` normally in the future?